# Triple Integral of Volume Concentration

Tags: mass, conservation-laws, units, volume

I am working on a problem involving volume concentrations which are defined as:
$$ \phi_i=\frac{V_i}{V} $$
and are thus dimensionless. My problem is in $3$D and I have assumed that the components in the binary mixture have a matched density. With that assumption, I believe it follows that conservation of mass implies conservation of volume concentrations (please correct me if that is wrong). I now want to show that this is in fact true for the numerical simulations I ran of the system. To do this, I take a triple integral of the concentration $\phi\equiv\phi_1$ (because it's a binary mixture my two components are $\phi$ and $1-\phi$). My question is what does this represent?
$$ \iiint_\Omega \phi $$
For all my simulations, it is constant which seems reassuring but I am not sure what this quantity represents. Since $\phi$ is dimensionless it seems like it should have units of Length cubed and hence is a volume; but this doesn't quite make sense to me. Total volume of the components should be conserved because the conservation of mass with constant density implies the concentration of volume (assuming no chemical reactions which is true for the system I am interested in). Is that what I am showing with my calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is as follows:

$$\iiint_{\Omega}\phi_i \ dV = \frac{V_i}{V}\iiint_{\Omega}dV = V_i $$

It is just the volume each substance occupies in the mixture (as long as $V_i$ does not depend on the total volume).